# Manipulate data inside conditions of findOne in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, get, lodash

I want to convert title in also lower case without considering space inside `findOne` conditions so that i can compare it with requested title.
New Post => newpost want to convert like this:

```
 app.get("/posts/:postName", function(req, res){
      const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName);
      
      Post.findOne({**title : requestedTitle**}, function(err, post){
        if (!err) {
            res.render("post", {
              title: post.title,
              content: post.body
            });
          }
        });
    });
```

Comment: do you want to save post here..save title to lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.replace(/ /g, '')` to delete all space, then you can use `.toLowerCase()` to lowercase the title.

Example code:

```
const requestedTitle = req.params.postName.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase();
```

Comment: const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName); this is working fine but when i'm trying to get title from my database it is with upper cases and spaces and i can't use .replace and .toLoweCase inside //findOne coditions Post.findOne({**title : requestedTitle**}